# Determine all positive integers $(a,m,n)$ such that $a^m+1|(a+1)^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Determine all triples of positive integers $(a,m,n)$ such that $a^m+1|(a+1)^n$.

y approach: Let $a,m,n,k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that  $k\geq 1$ and $$\dfrac{(a+1)^n}{a^m+1}=k\implies (a+1)^n=ka^m+k\qquad (*)$$ Suppose that $n>m$, since if $n\leq m$, then $$k=\dfrac{(a+1)^n}{a^m+1}\leq\dfrac{(a+1)^n}{a^n+1}<\dfrac{a^n+1}{a^n+1}=1\implies k<1$$
Now, of $(*)$, we have $$(a+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}a^k}=ka^m+k\implies {n\choose m}=k$$

Now, how I can continuous??, Is clear that $\{(1,m,n),(a,1,1),(a,1,n)\}$ are solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Have you created this problem yourself, or is it an olympiad problem you have picked from somewhere?

Comment: If $a=2$, then we need $a^m+1$ to divide a power of 3, hence, to be a power of 3, and it's known that this happens if and only if $m=1,3$. So, $(2,3,n)$ works for $n\ge2$, but $(2,m,n)$ does not work for any $m\ge4$. This suggests to me that this is a hard problem, to which you will not get a wholly satisfactory answer.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Hi! I don't know, a friend asked me for help, but I think this problem is really hard.

Comment: @MathUser As the answer below suggests, the problem is quite hard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows immediately from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem.

Problem appeared in the  IMOSL  2000 as a N4  so for a less nuclear solution  [see here](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h28215p174936).

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have with what you said is you're assumption that $\sum^n_{i=0} {{n}\choose{i}} a^i = ka^m + k$ implying ${{n}\choose{m}} = k$. You're not equating coefficients here because the expressions are equal, not equivalent.

Comment: Ohh ok. Then, you can give me some hint pls, thanks!