# Number Theory - Integers equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show the following?

> Let $x,m,n > 1$ be positive intgers. If $x^m+1$ divides $(x+1)^n$ then $m$ must be odd.

A [stronger question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001548/determine-all-positive-integers-a-m-n-such-that-am1a1n) has been posted but not answered on math.stackexchange. Another stronger claim, if correct, is at [Number Theory - Integer Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432499/number-theory-integer-equation) .

Comment: Please don't delete your question right after receiving an answer.

Comment: $x^{2m}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Why you have deleted your question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be an odd prime number such that $p|x^m+1$. Then $p|(x+1)^n$ and hence $p|x+1$. Thus $x\equiv -1\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$. We deduce that $x^m \equiv (-1)^m\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$. On the other hand by initial assumption
$$x^m\equiv -1\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$$
Hence $(-1)^m \equiv (-1)\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$ and thus $m$ must be odd, because $p\neq 2$.

So it suffices to consider the case that $x^m+1$ has no odd factors. Then $x^m+1 = 2^k$ for some $k\geq 1$. **Assume that $m$ is even.** Clearly $x$ is odd and hence $x^m+1 \equiv 2\,\mathrm{mod}\,4$. On the other hand $2^k \equiv 2\,\mathrm{mod}\,4$ if and only if $k=1$. Thus $k=1$ and hence $x^m+1 = 2$, but this is contradiction with $x>1$.